# How can i open new activity keeping the same drawer on the right/left?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

How can i open new activity(at listview element click) keeping the same drawer on the right/left?

Comment: P.S. the listview is one element of the drawer

Comment: I think [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) is a good option for that.

Comment: Can i do it without fragments? If you know a giude or somethings else please link it ty

Comment: I don't think there is a better way than fragments. There is TabActivity, but it provides very less customization options. However, I will try to check for more options in my free time, till then try to learn about fragments.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify a drawer layout for your new activity (in the XML) and copy over the same Navigation Drawer code from your original Activity in to your new Activity, it should work. If you were to do this, I would recommend moving all common code (such as any custom list adapters you may be using to populate the navigation list within the drawer, your onItemClickListener(), etc.) into its own class and having your two activities access the common methods from there. However, if you have the option of using fragments, as @Matt_9.0 suggested, it will make the navigation drawer more maintainable down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Check [This](http://www.fantageek.com/549/make-your-own-sliding-menu-on-android-tutorial-part-1/)
 is tutorial for what u want
Then too with bummi's suggestions , here is the code

XML layout

```
<!-- This holds our menu -->

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_menu_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/menu"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White" >

</FrameLayout>
```

this fragment is used to contain the different layouts whichever you want

com.package.appname.layout package MainLayout.class

```
public class MainLayout extends LinearLayout {

    // Duration of sliding animation, in miliseconds
    private static final int SLIDING_DURATION = 500;
    // Query Scroller every 16 miliseconds
    private static final int QUERY_INTERVAL = 16;

    // MainLayout width
    int mainLayoutWidth;

    // Sliding menu
    private View menu;

    // Main content
    private View content;
    private View subContent = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment);
    // menu does not occupy some right space
    // This should be updated correctly later in onMeasure
    private static int menuRightMargin = 150;

    // The state of menu
    private enum MenuState {
        HIDING,
        HIDDEN,
        SHOWING,
        SHOWN,
    };

    // content will be layouted based on this X offset
    // Normally, contentXOffset = menu.getLayoutParams().width = this.getWidth - menuRightMargin
    private int contentXOffset;

    // menu is hidden initially
    private MenuState currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;

    // Scroller is used to facilitate animation
    private Scroller menuScroller = new Scroller(this.getContext(),
            new EaseInInterpolator());

    // Used to query Scroller about scrolling position
    // Note: The 3rd paramter to startScroll is the distance
    private Runnable menuRunnable = new MenuRunnable();
    private Handler menuHandler = new Handler();

    // Previous touch position
    int prevX = 0;

    // Is user dragging the content
    boolean isDragging = false;

    // Used to facilitate ACTION_UP 
    int lastDiffX = 0;

    // Constructor

    // 3 parameters constructor seems to be unavailable in 2.3
    /*
    public MainLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    */

    public MainLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MainLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    // Overriding LinearLayout core methods

    // Ask all children to measure themselves and compute the measurement of this
    // layout based on the children
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        mainLayoutWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        menuRightMargin = mainLayoutWidth * 10 / 100;
        // Nothing to do, since we only care about how to layout
    }

    // This is called when MainLayout is attached to window
    // At this point it has a Surface and will start drawing. 
    // Note that this function is guaranteed to be called before onDraw

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        // Get our 2 child View
        menu = this.getChildAt(0);
        content = this.getChildAt(1);  
       content.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return MainLayout.this.onContentTouch(v, event);
            }
        });

        // Initially hide the menu
        menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Called from layout when this view should assign a size and position to each of its children
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        //Log.d("MainLayout.java onLayout()", "left " + left + " top " + top + " right " + right + " bottom " + bottom);
        //Log.d("MainLayout.java onLayout()", "getHeight " + this.getHeight() + " getWidth " + this.getWidth());

        // True if MainLayout 's size and position has changed
        // If true, calculate child views size
        if(changed) {
            // Note: LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out

            //Log.d("MainLayout.java onLayout()", "changed " + changed);

            // content View occupies the full height and width
            LayoutParams contentLayoutParams = (LayoutParams)content.getLayoutParams();
            contentLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
            contentLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth();

            // menu View occupies the full height, but certain width
            LayoutParams menuLayoutParams = (LayoutParams)menu.getLayoutParams();
            menuLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
            menuLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth() - menuRightMargin;          
        }

        // Layout the child views    
        menu.layout(left, top, right - menuRightMargin, bottom);
        content.layout(left + contentXOffset, top, right + contentXOffset, bottom);

    }

    // Custom methods for MainLayout

    // Used to show/hide menu accordingly
    public void toggleMenu() {
        // Do nothing if sliding is in progress
        if(currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
            return;

        switch(currentMenuState) {
        case HIDDEN:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;
            menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            menuScroller.startScroll(0, 0, menu.getLayoutParams().width,
                    0, SLIDING_DURATION);
            break;
        case SHOWN:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
            menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, -contentXOffset, 
                    0, SLIDING_DURATION);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        // Begin querying
        menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);

        // Invalite this whole MainLayout, causing onLayout() to be called
        this.invalidate();
    }

    // Query Scroller
    protected class MenuRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean isScrolling = menuScroller.computeScrollOffset();
            adjustContentPosition(isScrolling);
        }
    }

    // Adjust content View position to match sliding animation
    private void adjustContentPosition(boolean isScrolling) {
        int scrollerXOffset = menuScroller.getCurrX();

        //Log.d("MainLayout.java adjustContentPosition()", "scrollerOffset " + scrollerOffset);

        // Translate content View accordingly
        content.offsetLeftAndRight(scrollerXOffset - contentXOffset);

        contentXOffset = scrollerXOffset;

        // Invalite this whole MainLayout, causing onLayout() to be called
        this.invalidate();

        // Check if animation is in progress
        if (isScrolling)
            menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
        else
            this.onMenuSlidingComplete();
    }

    // Called when sliding is complete
    private void onMenuSlidingComplete() {
        switch (currentMenuState) {
        case SHOWING:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWN;
            break;
        case HIDING:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;
            menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }
    }

    // Make scrolling more natural. Move more quickly at the end
    // See the formula here http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/22/the-making-of-prixing-fly-in-app-menu-part-1/
    protected class EaseInInterpolator implements Interpolator {
        @Override
        public float getInterpolation(float t) {
            return (float)Math.pow(t-1, 5) + 1;
        }

    }

    // Is menu completely shown
    public boolean isMenuShown() {
        return currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWN;
    }

    // Handle touch event on content View
    public boolean onContentTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Do nothing if sliding is in progress
        if(currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
            return false;

        // getRawX returns X touch point corresponding to screen
        // getX sometimes returns screen X, sometimes returns content View X
        int curX = (int)event.getRawX();
        int diffX = 0;

        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Down x " + curX);
            prevX = curX;
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Move x " + curX);

            // Set menu to Visible when user start dragging the content View
            if(!isDragging) {
                isDragging = true;
                menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            // How far we have moved since the last position
            diffX = curX - prevX;

            // Prevent user from dragging beyond border
            if(contentXOffset + diffX <= 0) {
                // Don't allow dragging beyond left border
                // Use diffX will make content cross the border, so only translate by -contentXOffset
                diffX = -contentXOffset;
            } else if(contentXOffset + diffX > mainLayoutWidth - menuRightMargin) {
                // Don't allow dragging beyond menu width
                diffX = mainLayoutWidth - menuRightMargin - contentXOffset;
            }

            // Translate content View accordingly
            content.offsetLeftAndRight(diffX);

            contentXOffset += diffX;

            // Invalite this whole MainLayout, causing onLayout() to be called
            this.invalidate();

            prevX = curX;
            lastDiffX = diffX;
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Up x " + curX);

            Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Up lastDiffX " + lastDiffX);

            // Start scrolling
            // Remember that when content has a chance to cross left border, lastDiffX is set to 0
            if(lastDiffX > 0) {
                // User wants to show menu
                currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;

                // No need to set to Visible, because we have set to Visible in ACTION_MOVE
                //menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Up contentXOffset " + contentXOffset);

                // Start scrolling from contentXOffset
                menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, menu.getLayoutParams().width - contentXOffset,
                        0, SLIDING_DURATION);
            } else if(lastDiffX < 0) {
                // User wants to hide menu
                currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
                menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, -contentXOffset, 
                        0, SLIDING_DURATION);
            }

            // Begin querying
            menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);

            // Invalite this whole MainLayout, causing onLayout() to be called
            this.invalidate();

            // Done dragging
            isDragging = false;
            prevX = 0;
            lastDiffX = 0;
            return true;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now create fragment layouts and call them in the MainACtivity.class
like

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ImageButton ibMenu;
    View view;
    MotionEvent events;
     boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
    ImageButton iv,ivabout_content;
    MainLayout mainLayout;
    // ListView menu
    private ListView lvMenu;
    private String[] lvMenuItems;
    TextView tvTitle;
    public View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mainLayout = (MainLayout) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_home, null);
        setContentView(mainLayout);

         // Init menu
        lvMenuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
        lvMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_menu_listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> menuAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lvMenuItems);
        lvMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
        iv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibHomeLatestEvent);
        ivabout_content = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibAboutLearn);
        lvMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onMenuItemClick(parent,view,position,id);
            }

        });
        ibMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_content_button_menu);
        ibMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                toggleMenu(v);
            }

        });
        tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_content_title);
        FragmentManager fm = HomeActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        ft.add(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
        ft.commit(); 
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return mainLayout.onContentTouch(v, event);
            }
        };
        iv.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);     

    }

    public void toggleMenu(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mainLayout.toggleMenu();
    }

    protected void onMenuItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String selectedItem = lvMenuItems[position];
        String currentItem = tvTitle.getText().toString();

        // Do nothing if selectedItem is currentItem
        if(selectedItem.compareTo(currentItem)==0){
            mainLayout.toggleMenu();
            return;
        }
    FragmentManager fm = HomeActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft =  fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = null;


    if(selectedItem.compareTo("Home") == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentHome();
    } else if(selectedItem.compareTo("About") == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentAbout();
    } else if(selectedItem.compareTo("What's new") == 0) {
        fragment = new Fragmentnew();
    } else if(selectedItem.compareTo("Things to do") == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentThingsToDo();
    } else if(selectedItem.compareTo("Holiday in Lavasa") == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentHolidayInLavasa();
    } else if(selectedItem.compareTo("Offers") == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentOffers();
    } else if(selectedItem.compareTo("Getting to Lavasa") == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentGettingLavasa();
    } else if(selectedItem.compareTo("Map") == 0){
         fragment = new FragmentMap();
    } else if(selectedItem.compareTo("Downloads") == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentDownloads();
    } else if(selectedItem.compareTo("Help Desk") == 0) {

    }
         if(fragment != null) {
             // Replace current fragment by this new one
             ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();
             // Set title accordingly
             tvTitle.setText(selectedItem);
         }

         // Hide menu anyway
         mainLayout.toggleMenu();
     }

     @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mainLayout.isMenuShown()) {
             mainLayout.toggleMenu();
         }
         else  if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
             super.onBackPressed();
             return;
         } 
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
             doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;   

            }
        }, 2000);
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

If you want further help let me know..